Какие файлы необходимы для компиляции проекта и запуска тестов?
Изучаю C#. Перефразируя вопрос из заголовка, какие файлы я должен включать в комит на GIT? Данный вопрос вызван тем, что создавая простенькую утилитку весом всего в несколько килобайт, при добавлении в проект файла с тестами и подключении фреймворка для тестирования размер проекта увеличивается до 100Мб, а количество файлов и папок с пары десятков до нескольких тысяч.
Посему хотелось бы раз и навсегда разобраться с этим, чтобы репозиторий оставался чистым, а проекты не выбрасывались в корзину из-за того, что в них стало невозможно разобраться.
Итак:

Какие файлы проекта комитить? Я знаю, что это должны быть файлы, необходимые для компиляции проекта тем, кто вытянет этот комит, но вот какие конкретно? Я новичок и только учусь, и потому без подсказки или наводки на то, что почитать по теме, самостоятельно разобраться вряд ли смогу.
Нужно ли комитить свои тесты? Лично мне бы хотелось их сохранять, но тогда опять же - какие файлы, относящиеся к тестам, комитить?
При работе над проектом в корне папки проекта создается несколько подпапок (например bin, obj, packages, Properties, TestResults). Содержится ли в них что-то необходимое для компиляции, или всё необходимое лежит только в корне папки проекта, и на внутренние папки можно не обращать внимания и просто добавить в gitignore?
В каком файле находятся ссылки? Например из файла с тестами на то, что тестируем. У каждого проекта внутри решения свои ссылки, или есть какой-то общий файл для всех?
Немного не по теме: Если у меня есть, например, dll-ка, которую я хочу подключить к проекту, как можно это сделать? Мне потребуется для этого проект, в котором создавалась эта библиотека, и который нужно подключать к общему решению, или можно прикрутить только сам файл dll? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Спасибо за ответ! Стандартные-то gitignore есть - и тот пробовал, что студия ставит на свой встроенный гит, и тот, что предлагается разработчиками git extension. Всё равно файлов куча, а какие из них важные а какие нет, неизвестно. Думал есть рецепт какой-то...

Не, обычно именно правильный .gitignore решает.

А "правильный" - он один для всех, или для каждого проекта нужно свой собирать? Можно ли вместо файлов, подлежащих игнорированию, указать наоборот - файлы, которые нужно отслеживать, а все остальные (неуказанные) игнорировать?

Эээ, ну во-первых уже по названию этого файла понятно, что он задаёт шаблоны именно для файлов, которые нужно игнорировать. А во-вторых все файлы, которые вы кладёте в отслеживаемый каталог и так будут отслеживаться по умолчанию. В общем, всё-таки вам придётся задавать файлы и каталоги, которые нужно игнорить. А что касается конкретики, можете глянуть сюда, например: https://github.com/github/gitignore Универсальных вроде нет, но бывают под конкретную среду, скажем так. Там есть для VisualStudio вариант, например.

Спасибо за ссылку, сейчас посмотрим. Ну а гитигнор - просто название, дающее общее представление о назначении файла. Но внутри него есть всякие префиксы, постфиксы, символы и проч., указывающие, что и с чем нужно делать. Можно перечислить файлы для игнора по именам, а можно перечислить их расширения без имени. Можно перечислить каталоги и отдельные ветки этих каталогов. Так что предположение что должно быть возможно указать конкретные файлы для отслеживания вполне логично, тем более что файлов этих намного меньше, чем мусора.

А, я был не прав - таки есть инвертирование правил через знак восклицания, но использовать нужно умеючи )  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820310/8324991

тут весьма много вопросов, и не менее много ответов, но главный вопрос - не задан; и вот же он - а нужен ли гит? в 95% - не нужен, и изначально нужно решить этот вопрос, ну потому что если [в 95% случаев] вы будете понимать, что гит - не нужен, то тогда вопросы с гитом отпадают сами собой, и тем не менее [в 5% случаев] вопросы с гитом - конечно же остаются

Стандартный набор файлов такой: все, кроме bin, obj, папок IDE (.vs, .idea и др.), папки git (.git), ну и файла .user. Остальное все зависит от того, что именно вы используете, какие расширения, какая IDE, и так далее. Другими словами, если у вас условный, чистый консольный проект, то все, что относится к самому проекту - это Program.cs и файл .csproj, все, если это решение, то дополнительно файл .sln, все остальное мусор, другие типы проектов аналогично, только со своим набором классов/окон и т.д.

CrazyElf, спасибо!
InterceptorTSK, у меня не стоит этот вопрос - Гит нужен как воздух, в том или ином виде, но нужен. И это не стереотип, а собственный опыт. Если знаете вариант лучше, кроме "просто не использовать и всё", то будет интересно узнать.
EvgeniyZ, спасибо!

